# Adding a button on top of googleMapView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I'm trying to add a UiButton on top of googleMapView.

I want to have a another button to open my Google Maps app for navigation from my app.

I tried adding a button programmatically and using xib.. its not working in both ways. (not showing).

Do you guys have any idea about it. I'm using swift

Comment: When I Google `Swift adding a button on top of googleMapView` there seem to be lots of useful results, have you tried them all and none worked? If yes - can you clarify what you tried and didn't work?

Comment: I wouldn't post this if those worked :)

Comment: Well, many do, and it's hard to tell who Googled beforehand and who didn't. To avoid people just replicating all the advice in the other questions (which won't help you), please add some details about what approaches you already tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try adding the button as a subview.

create the button like this:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.backgroundColor = .blue
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
button.setTitle("My Button", for: .normal)
```

and add it as a subview to your `googleMapView` like this:

```
googleMapView.addSubview(button)
```